# who can help me to explain the function of this variable in the source code?

Tags: javascript, promise

I just checked some details of [this repo - faye](https://faye.jcoglan.com/), the author implemented the Promise in scratch which is impressed me. There are something confused me: in [this line](https://github.com/faye/faye/blob/60141e8d3942a88ba3de6a9b3aef9503bc1bb1e6/src/util/promise.js#L41), `calls` seems useless, just want to know if it is a trick for some asynchronous issues, or just a redundant declaration?

---

```
// L41 in src/util/promise.js 
var execute = function(promise, task) {
  if (typeof task !== 'function') return;

  var calls = 0; // weird variable

  var resolvePromise = function(value) {
    if (calls++ === 0) resolve(promise, value);
  };

  var rejectPromise = function(reason) {
    if (calls++ === 0) reject(promise, reason);
  };

  try {
    task(resolvePromise, rejectPromise);
  } catch (error) {
    rejectPromise(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Why would it be useless? It's used in both functions below it.

Comment: It is some sort of safety check to make sure that the resolve or reject is only triggered once in case the task calls it more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's being used to detect if you try to resolve or reject the promise multiple times. When you call these functions, it increments the `count` variable, and then tests its original value. If the original value was `0`, this is the first time either of the functions was calls, so it continues and calls `resolve()` or `reject()`. Otherwise it just returns.

The logic is equivalent to this:

```js
var execute = function(promise, task) {
  if (typeof task !== 'function') return;

  var firstTime = true;

  var resolvePromise = function(value) {
    if (firstTime) {
      firstTime = false;
      resolve(promise, value);
    }
  };

  var rejectPromise = function(reason) {
    if (firstTime) {
      firstTime = false;
      reject(promise, value);
    }
  };

  try {
    task(resolvePromise, rejectPromise);
  } catch (error) {
    rejectPromise(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: that is pretty clear, and thx so much!!

Answer (score -4):

It really seems that calls is not doing anything, maybe they had a different implementation, but it ended up starting it at 0 and a meaningless variable was left.

Comment: "*It really seems that calls is not doing anything*" what? It's most definitely being used in both the resolve and reject implementations. That's *something*. It's not nothing.